# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'

Tags: c, header-files

While compiling a C program in LINUX, I get the foll. error:

```
stream.h:1123: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
stream.h:1124: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mblk_t'
stream.h:1125: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mblk_t'
```

Line 1123,1124 and 1125 are given below:

```
__STREAMS_EXTERN int adjmsg(mblk_t *mp, register ssize_t length);
__STREAMS_EXTERN mblk_t *allocb(size_t size, unsigned int priority);
__STREAMS_EXTERN mblk_t *copyb(register mblk_t *mp);
```

The C program includes a header file which in turn includes stream.h
Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: Just a note, it seems your terminal is nor configured for proper unicode (usually UTF-8 on linux). So the `â` characters really should be quotes. Making the message much more readable.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I have now configured my putty with UTF-8 and â appear as quotes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear the context of your code but it seems to me that you're using the OpenSSL library (or you're doing copy & paste from that source code).

The `streams_fastcall` macro is defined in the `kmem.h` header file. Did you include it? If you're just doing copy & paste you simply have to add this lines before your `STREAMS_EXTERN` definition:

```
#ifndef streams_fastcall
#if defined __i386__ || defined __x86_64__ || defined __k8__
#define streams_fastcall __attribute__((__regparm__(3)))
#else
#define streams_fastcall
#endif
#endif
```

**Note**: `streams_fastcall` *sounds* like the Microsoft Specific (but widely used on Windows) calling convention named `__fastcall`. I guess they used that name because it uses
the `regparm` attribute to specify that some arguments should be passed using registers instead of the stack and this is what `__fastcall` defines (or simply because it's simply faster! lol)

Comment: Hi Adrino, yes I have included kmem.h file.

Comment: Headers from the library itself should be OK so I **guess** you're doing something wrong with the order of your inclusions. Check it's included before "stream.h"

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty clear that `__STREAMS_EXTERN` is defined in a way that is messing things up.

How is `__STREAMS_EXTERN` defined?

Comment: #ifndef __STREAMS_EXTERN
    #define __STREAMS_EXTERN __EXTERN streams_fastcall
    #endif

Comment: #ifndef __EXTERN 
#define __EXTERN extern 
#endif

Comment: @Tinyspark The compiler doesn't understand `streams_fastcall`, seems to be a Windows thing.

Comment: Daniel, I don't get what you mean by 'Windows thing'. Also, I am compiling my code in a Linux environment.

Comment: @Tinyspark Yes, you're compiling on Linux. The compiler doesn't understand `streams_fastcall`. `streams_fastcall` looks like one of the calling-convention macros common on Windows. So I guess the code has originally been written for Windows. I may have guessed wrong, of course, happens every other day.

Comment: @DanielFischer it's not a Windows thing, it's a macro defined in the OpenSSL library that simply mimic the name and the behavior of that calling convention (__fastcall).

Comment: Hi Adrino, as u said, I have streams_fastcall in the libraries of openss7.  Any other reason why STREAMS_EXTERN is causing error?

Answer (score 0):

In case the error is not related to any missing ; or similar syntax error in your code, check for a bad referencing to the openSSL includes.

With your openSSL includes err.h and evp.h in /opt/openssl/include/openssl and you compile directives being -I. -L /opt/openssl/lib, -l crypto and -l dl

having this include in your .h file provokes the error: #include  (same with err.h).

Simply replace it with this include: #include  to solve it.