# Why do I get "error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int’" ?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

> processpairs2.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘int’

Is the error I get everytime I compile my file, the error references me to line 7, which is where I declare the `main()` function.

my main's function is declared as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

does anyone know what's causing this?

any help is greatly appreciated.

line 1-6 is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 10
void checkhighestpair();
int *ptotal, *pval1, *pval2
```

Comment: Please show us line 1-6.

Comment: What do you have before that line?

Comment: give your code you must have declared some `struct` or something typedefed and missing `; `there so you are getting it

Comment: We're not mind readers. Would you expect someone to know what is wrong with your car without seeing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '\_\_attribute\_\_' before 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499389/error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-int) and **about 100 more questions** you can see in the `Related` list to the right, and that would have appeared as you typed the subject of your question. At least take the time to do a basic search for your error message before posting. Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, you copied line 1-6 and you *still didn't notice* this mistake?

Answer (score 7):

Are you not just missing the ; on the last line there?...

Answer (score 6):

Append a `;` after:

```
int *ptotal, *pval1, *pval2
```

so it becomes:

```
int *ptotal, *pval1, *pval2;
```